# Generating pages vue-i18n nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxtjs, nuxt-i18n

I am trying to run ‘nuxt generate’ for a multi language website (de and en) and I get the following error: `ERROR Error generating route "/de": This page could not be found`

I get the error only when I set `defaultLocale: 'de'`, on `defaultLocale: 'en'` it works perfectly. I tried playing with the plugin config but to no avail.

This is my configuration:
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1W0H.png)

These are the generated pages:
[generated pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkE8y.png)

If defaultLocale: 'en', it doesn’t try to generate a page for e.g. “/en”

From what I can see in /dist folder, if default locale is on 'de' it create the root pages, a folder 'en' for English pages and it tries to create another folder 'de' -> which fails. This is not replicable for default locale set to 'en', it creates the root pages and a folder 'de' for the german one, without any new 'en' folder.

Comment: We will probably need your configuration in `nuxt.config.js` and your file structure to help here.

Comment: Have you set the "generate" property in `nuxt.config.js` ? If yes, can you share it ? If the defaultLocale is de and your prefix strategy is set to prefix_except_default, it should not generate the /de route.